# Control iTunes from Spotlight (or similar)

Tags: macos, itunes, music, plugins

Is there some sort add on or program that lets me easily change (and choose) songs using keyboard shortcuts (or perhaps Spotlight)?

The ideal program would add iTunes indexing to Spotlight and allow me to change songs by searching for them in Spotlight (but then not switch the focus to iTunes). I do believe that there was a plugin for Launchy on Windows to do a similar thing.

Is such a program available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using a combination of the programs suggested here, but they were all lacking something. Turns out this 'something' is exactly what [CoverSutra](http://www.sophiestication.com/coversutra/) excels at.

> Isn't it annoying to switch to iTunes just to select a different song or pause playback?
>
> CoverSutra gives you a handy and attractive way to control iTunes without having to leave your current application.
>
> See what's currently playing or enjoy your album artwork. Don't let yourself be distracted from your work... CoverSutra is never in your way but always by your side.

After just a few minutes using it, I have already fallen in love with it, mainly for it's music search:

> We all know how Spotlight revolutionizes searching, in general on your Mac. Well, what if you could have that power specifically for your music? All done in a slick, stylish way. Well, with CoverSutra you now can. Extremely fast and robust iTunes searching is just a click or keyboard shortcut away.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[SizzlingKeys](http://www.yellowmug.com/sk4it/) allows you to control iTunes from any application using keyboard shortcuts. The free edition has all the features you require.

[image]

There is also [Quicksilver](http://docs.blacktree.com/quicksilver/what_is_quicksilver), for a more "search" type of feel like spotlight:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Quicksilver is the *most* flexible iTunes controller. You have two ways to control iTunes. Firstly you can search and control through its interface (this is using the radial constellation plugin):

[image]

Quicksilver has a brilliant trigger interface, which is basically global key mappings, and has a dedicated iTunes plugin to do very fast system-wide control:

[image]

[image]

See these tutorials on how to set it up:

- http://macapper.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/05/quicksilver1.png
- http://lifehacker.com/259373/control-itunes-with-quicksilver

The latest version is the open-source branch hosted here:

http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-alchemy/

Answer (score 2):

[Google Quick Search Box](http://code.google.com/p/qsb-mac/) can do that too.

[image: google qsb iTunes control]

Answer (score 2):

In the same vein as Quicksilver and Google Quick Search Box, [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) and [Butler](http://www.many-tricks.com/butler/). Personally I use LaunchBar and find it excellent for doing just the task you asked.

Answer (score 1):

To control iTunes with keyboard shortcuts, I use [Bowtie](http://bowtieapp.com/)
You can configure shortcuts for a bunch of things and one of the shortcuts makes a little search appear to search for songs, album or artist. Also, Bowtie can put the album cover on your desktop and it customizable.

Answer (score 0):

I am using coverstream, it has really good keyboard control.

Search is really powerful and it has become the best way for me to control iTunes playback.

I like it because is very keyboard oriented.

http://coverstream.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) PowerPack has a Mini Player that allows searching and playing a song/album without switching to iTunes.

[image: Alfred iTunes Mini Player]